# Hiding widgets for specific user roles

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So its about hiding widgets for specific user roles excluding Admin.Using custom sidebar plugin i don't want to be display on users end.Listed all Dashboard widgets through

```
     function list_active_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    foreach (array_keys($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']) as $name) {
        echo '<div>' . $name . '</div>';
    }
 }
 add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'list_active_dashboard_widgets');
```

and found ***customsidebars-mb***

What i am doing without succes is adding this code to hide sidebar options widget from users panel keeping it on admin panel.

```
      function disable_default_dashboard_widgets() {remove_meta_box('customsidebars-mb', 'dashboard', 'normal');
  }
  add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_default_dashboard_widgets');
  if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
          add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'disable_default_dashboard_widgets');
  }
```

**

### Store front Theme Woocommerce Plugin

**Will be phasing out all plugins with codes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one in your functions.php,

```
add_action( 'widgets_init',  'remove_widgets_wpse_89138' , 15 );

function remove_widgets_wpse_89138()
{
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin
if( !is_admin() )
    return;

// Grab current user info
global $current_user;

// Check for specific user
/*
$username = $current_user->user_login;
if( 'the_user_login' != $username)
    return;
*/

// Check for capability
if( current_user_can( 'add_users' ) )
    return;

unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
}
```

Hope this will helps you. For more please visit, [URL 1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-widgets/), [URL 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/hide-certain-widgets-from-specific-user-roles-in-admin)

Comment: its a sidebar created by plugin custum sidebar under user panel